# Including other project as library in Android project without JAR management?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Simple question, but I couldn't find anything about it. Is there a way to have my Android project include another Java project in the same workspace without recompiling a JAR for that library every time I change anything? Or can I automate JAR generation or something?

I've tried just adding the project to the build path and it makes the definitions visible in the Android app, but they're not linked (NoClassDefFoundError at runtime).

Comment: Eclipse? Command line? Something else?

Comment: Eclipse, as noted in the tags.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on project, which you want to be a library, "Properties", "Android", scroll to the bottom, toggle "Is library", add to your main project's build path.

Comment: Does a library have to be an Android library to be eligible for inclusion? Because it seems dex exports it as empty .jar.

Comment: Here is some useful info about this question http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Comment: Thanks, that helped fix my problem. In the end I just had to make it into an Android project.